# Сортировка массива структур Qt

Tags: c++, qt

В бинарный файл в потоке записывается структура worker

```
struct worker{
    QString wname;
    QString wlastname;
    int wsalary;
};
```

В момент чтения файла нужно в MessageBox вывести содержимое файла, в порядке убывания wsalary, т.е. нужно считать содержимое файла и отсортировать, сделал следующее решение

```
void MainWindow::on_ReadFilepushButton_clicked()
{
    worker man;
    QFile file (FName);

    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        QDataStream output(&file);
        worker* mens = new worker;
        worker temp;
        QString s = "";
        int stuctIterator = 0;
        while(!output.atEnd()){
            output >> man.wname >> man.wlastname >> man.wsalary;
            stuctIterator++;
            qDebug() << "1"; 
            mens[stuctIterator].wname = man.wname; //Место сбоя
            qDebug() << mens[stuctIterator].wname;
            mens[stuctIterator].wlastname = man.wlastname;
            qDebug() << mens[stuctIterator].wlastname;
            mens[stuctIterator].wsalary = man.wsalary;
            qDebug() << mens[stuctIterator].wsalary;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < stuctIterator - 1; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < stuctIterator - i - 1; j++) {
                if (mens[j].wsalary > mens[j + 1].wsalary){
                    temp = mens[j];
                    mens[j] = mens[j + 1];
                    mens[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < stuctIterator; i++){
            s += QString::number(i + 1) + ") "
                    + mens[i].wname + " "
                    + mens[i].wlastname + " "
                    + QString::number(mens[i].wsalary) + "\n";
        }
        delete mens;

        file.close();

        QMessageBox::about(this, FName, s);
    } else
        QMessageBox::critical(this, FName, "file does not exist");
}
```

Программа перестаёт отвечать в том месте где помечено место сбоя, ума не приложу в чем ошибка и как исправить

Comment: У вас `mens` - не массив! А просто указатель. Для того, чтобы это был массив используйте `new worker [n]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    worker* mens = new worker;
    worker temp;
    QString s = "";
    int stuctIterator = 0;
    while(!output.atEnd()){
        output >> man.wname >> man.wlastname >> man.wsalary;
        stuctIterator++;
        qDebug() << "1"; 
        mens[stuctIterator].wname = man.wname; //Место сбоя
```

Обратите внимание: вы используете указатель `mens` и выделяете динамически память под одно значение `worker`. А затем используете его как массив - это уже не верно! Для начала, если вам нужен массив, то следует использовать `new worker [n]` - именно `new []`! Второе: какой размер массива должен быть? Тобишь нужно значение `n`. Это значение должно быть таким, чтобы не произошел выход за пределы массива (тобишь выделенной памяти) - иначе проблемы гарантированы!

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!